# Firebase : How do I change MVElqwKb7MtE1nIXLUH to the email address that I registered with?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the picture, how do I change the name to the email address of the registration.

Note Use the Auth in firebase process.

Destination: When I log in, I want to show me the email address in DataBase instead of MVElqwKb7MtE1nIXLUH.

```
    FIRE_INSTANCE = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://bau-database-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");

    FIRE_DB = FIRE_INSTANCE.getReference("user");

    FIRE_INSTANCE.getReference("app_title").setValue("Realtime Database");


    FIRE_INSTANCE.getReference("app_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App title Updateed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String titile = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed : " + databaseError.toException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared writes the user to the database, so it'll be hard to say the exact change. But overall, you seem to be calling `push()` (which generates the `-M...` keys) and you want to instead use `child(user.email)` or something like that.  Note that you will have to encode the email address, as it contains a `.` and that value is not allowed in keys in the database. Most custom is to replace `.` in the email address with `,` (comma) which *is* allowed

Comment: You have modified the code @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I merely removed whitespace and empty lines to reduce the need to scroll. There was no call to `push()` in the original post. If you want to double check that, you can see it in the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66663922/revisions).

Comment: So basically you want to change the keys that are pushed IDs to email addresses?  Is this what you want? Please respond with @AlexMamo